# Identifying whitespace vs other character runs in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the strings:

```
strs = [
  "foo",
  "    ",
  "Hello \n there",
  " Ooh, leading and trailing space!  ",
]
```

I want a simple method identifying all contiguous runs of whitespace and non-whitespace characters, in order, along with whether the run is whitespace or not:

```
strs.each{ |str| p find_whitespace_runs(str) }
#=> [ {k:1, s:"foo"} ],
#=> [ {k:0, s:"    "} ],
#=> [ {k:1, s:"Hello"}, {k:0, s:" \n "}, {k:1, s:"World"} ],
#=> [
#=>   {k:0, s:" "},
#=>   {k:1, s:"Ooh,"},
#=>   {k:0, s:" "},
#=>   {k:1, s:"leading"},
#=>   {k:0, s:" "},
#=>   {k:1, s:"and"},
#=>   {k:0, s:" "},
#=>   {k:1, s:"trailing"},
#=>   {k:0, s:" "},
#=>   {k:1, s:"space!"},
#=>   {k:0, s:"  "},
#=> ]
```

This almost works, but includes a single leading `{k:0, s:""}` group whenever the string does not start with whitespace:

```
def find_whitespace_runs(str)
  str.split(/(\S+)/).map.with_index do |s,i|
    {k:i%2, s:s}
  end
end
```

<sub>*Real-world motivation: writing [a syntax highlighter](https://github.com/Phrogz/coderay/blob/master/lib/coderay/scanners/lua.rb#L152) that distinguishes whitespace from non-whitespace in otherwise-unlexed code.*</sub>

Comment: Out of curiosity, why 0/1 instead of falsy/truthy?

Comment: @WayneConrad Mostly because it made the third example results fit on one line :) Also, as seen in the link from the question, I'm actually calling `each` and indexing into an array of labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def find_whitespace_runs(str)
  str.scan(/((\s+)|(\S+))/).map { |full, ws, nws|
    { :k => nws ? 1 : 0, :s => full } 
  }
end
```

Comment: Tricky! I want to test this a bit before committing, but I think you win the gold star.

Comment: Yup, this is both correct and just as fast as my current `split`-based hack. (And has the potential to be slightly better in terms of memory.) Nice work.

Comment: Perfect, perfetto, parfait, perfekt, perfecto, 完ぺき, 完美, 완전한 !

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I dislike the presence of the `unless empty?` (and `compact`).

```
def find_whitespace_runs(str)
  str.split(/(\S+)/).map.with_index do |s,i|
    {k:i%2, s:s} unless s.empty?
  end.compact
end
```

I will happily upvote any answer that produces the correct results, and will accept any answer that is more elegant or demonstrably more efficient.